# List appears as null if used outside the local variable scope in Java

Tags: java, android

**Background**: I am creating a turnbased multiplayer game. The user is randomly matched with another user. Upon matching, the user is given a list of words, which he will need to use for the reminder of the game. This list of words is randomly chosen from a much larger list.

**Problem**:  I get the index out of bounds exception when I run the app (exception points to line where `mCopy` is used outside the `query.getFirstInBackground` code block. When I debugged the app and set breakpoints on `mCopy`(list of words available to user) , it showed an empty list. It should be noted that the wordsList is appearing in the backend, and if I execute the all the code in the `query.getFirstInBackground` block, I do not have a problem. However, what I want is that once `mCopy` retrieves the list from Parse, I can use mCopy anywhere in the class.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class PlayGameActivity extends Activity {
    protected LinkedList<String> mCopy; //This is a global variable where words are stored


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        mCopy = new LinkedList<String>();

        Intent cameFromGIPActivity = getIntent();
        mCameFromGIPActivity = cameFromGIPActivity.getStringExtra(ExTRA_GamesInProgress);

        // if this is null, that means opp came from FindingOpp Activity
        if (mCameFromGIPActivity == null) {

            //use the opponent name as a key to get selected words(value)
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_GAMES_IN_PROGRESS);
            query.whereMatches(ParseConstants.KEY_OPPONENT_NAME, mOpponentName);

            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject gameInfo, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "success!");

                        mSavedWordList = gameInfo.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SELECTED_WORDS);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        ArrayList<String> finalWordList = gson.fromJson(mSavedWordList, type);
                        mCopy.addAll(finalWordList);
    });




         word1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word1); //I get the index out of bound exception here,
         word1.setText(mCopy.get(1));
         word1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

**Edit1**: I previously stated that I get no exception in the logCat, I was wrong. I get the index out of bound exception. Apologies.

Comment: What do you get if you log finalWordList right after it's created? On your edit: I assume the IndexOutOfBoundsException is on the mCopy.get(1) line? If so, it's just a symptom of mCopy being empty, once that's solved the IndexOutOfBoundsException should go away, although it would be good practice to check if mCopy is empty instead of just assuming it's not.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be empty? If `mCameFromGIPActivity` is not `null`, it will definitely be empty because you aren't adding anything to it. If `mCameFromGIPActivity` is `null`, it will probably be empty when you get to `word1.setText(mCopy.get(1));` because you appear to only be adding to it in another thread.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct about the Exception. I know that mCopy is empty, when I ran the app in debug mode, it shows that mCopy has size 0. What I do not understand is why that's the case. 

Also, I am unable to either set breakpoints on `finalWordList` or retrieve the log statement.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think you and Arkantos are saying the same thing. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getFirstInBackground(com.parse.GetCallback)), `getFirstInBackground` retrieves a `ParseObject` based on your query in a separate thread without blocking/freezing the execution in your current thread. Once the fetch is complete, `done()` in callback object is invoked.

Even though it looks your statements are ordered one after the other in your code, `getFirstInBackground` is an Asynchronous operation. So fetch will be running in a different thread, while the remaining statements in your code are executed.

As your `mCopy` is updated within `done` method, any code that relies on the update should be executed in the same method like below.

```
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

               @Override
               public void done(ParseObject gameInfo, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "success!");

                         mSavedWordList = gameInfo.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SELECTED_WORDS);
                         Gson gson = new Gson();
                         Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                            }.getType();
                         ArrayList<String> finalWordList = gson.fromJson(mSavedWordList, type);
                         mCopy.addAll(finalWordList);
                         /* mCopy is updated here - so use it now*/
                         word1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word1); 
                         word1.setText(mCopy.get(1));
                         word1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());


    });
```

Comment: This is exactly how I am getting my code to work right now. But because there are multiple activities from where the user can enter `PlayGameActivity`, and there are lots of words, I would not like to have my code be so verbose, although it seems that there is no other way around it?

Comment: If you have multiple words, why don't you loop through the list to set onclick listener ?

Comment: Should have thought of that. Thanks!